# h2o cross validation standard deviation is different from the manually computed standard deviation, why is that

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, h2o

I tried to use h2o's cross-validation. metrics, but I found the standard deviation is different from what I have calculated

```
  mean           sd cv_1_valid cv_2_valid cv_3_valid cv_4_valid cv_5_valid        model
auc   0.9512599 0.0058884337 0.96505374  0.9521365  0.9406109  0.9451134 0.95338506          drf

sd(c(0.96505374,0.9521365,0.9406109,0.9451134,0.95338506) )
[1] 0.009310416
mean(c(0.96505374,0.9521365,0.9406109,0.9451134,0.95338506) )
[1] 0.9512599
```

Mean is the same but sd is different, is there other ways of calculating this?

Comment: Can you please check this [link](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4975)

Comment: Thank you, I have noticed that problem of cross-validation metrics but I am still confused on how does the sd was calculated in the example above.

Comment: I filed a bug to look into this, I am not sure why they don't match: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-6413

Comment: Ok, Thank you! Hope it gets resolved.